# Can a VS2013 WPF App run on a Win8.1 Tablet?

Tags: wpf, tablet

We want to create a GUI for an embedded system. Communication will be via USB/RS232. We are considering a Win8.1 tablet.

Can a VS2013 Community WPF App be installed and run on a Win8.1 tablet?
Bill

Comment: If the tablet is running  the full version of Windows, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Windows 8.1 - Yes
- WindowsRT 8.1 - No